# Remove font size and family from font tag within div using simple html dom

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
<div align="justify>
     <div align="justify">
     <p><font color="#333333" face="Arial" style="font-size:12px">
     <div style="text-align: justify;"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="4" color="#990000">

bunch more stuff here

</div> <!-- end first div -->
```

So I have the code above and am pulling the content using Simple HTML DOM based on that first "justify".  The first text in actual HTML starts where "bunch more stuff here" is.

How can I remove (or change) the size attribute, specifically that size="4"?  Hopefully with out counting font tags since that code is not consistent.

Current simple HTML DOM:

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.regnumchristi.org/english/articulos/articulo.phtml?se=363&ca=975&te=735&id=20302#art_der6');

//delete links
foreach($html->find('a') as $e)
    $e->outertext = '';

//show title
$e = $html->find('font[style="font-size:28px"]',1);
    echo $e->outertext . '';    
// show date
$e = $html->find('font[color="#9A9A9A"]',0);
    echo '<div style="float: right; margin-top: -40px;">'. $e->outertext . '</div>';
//show day  
$e = $html->find('div[align="justify"]',0);
    echo strip_tags($e->innertext) . '';

 //show rest    
$stuff = $html->find('div[align="justify"]',1);
 echo $stuff->saveHTML($tag);
    echo '' . $stuff->outertext . '</ div>';
?>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS classes and ditching the inline styles?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that like

$('font').attr('style','font-size:4px')

Comment: Could use a little help explaining exactly how to do that

Comment: You just apply $('font').attr('size', '0');  in your jQuery code it will update size attribute with 0 value.

Comment: I guess that could work if I could apply it to a portion of the page instead of the entire page.

Comment: Yes, you can either apply for complete page or can also apply for a section but this code will work for complete page.